# order by with distinct name

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

My table:

```
PageOrderID   PageName
3            Citation Number   
3            Citation Number  
3            Citation Number
1            Account Info 
1            Account Info 
1            Account Info
```

I wanted to order it Pagename according to PageOrderID, but distinct PageNames.

I have tried the following but it is not working:

```
select PageOrderID,distinct(PageName) from ScreenMaster order by PageOrderID
```

What is the mistake?

O/P:

```
PageOrderID   PageName
1              Account Info
3              Citation Number
```

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: @juergend i have mentioned it in last

Comment: `DISTINCT` can not be used for single column in `SELECT`, only on all columns you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select DISTINCT PageOrderID,PageName from ScreenMaster
order by PageOrderID
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to group by:

```
SELECT PageOrderID,PageName
FROM dbo.ScreenMaster 
GROUP BY PageOrderID,PageName
ORDER BY PageOrderID
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c87d3/3/0)

```
PAGEORDERID     PAGENAME
    1           Account Info
    3           Citation Number
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple,

```
select distinct * from ScreenMaster 
order by PageOrderID
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select DISTINCT PageOrderID,PageName from ScreenMaster group by PageOrderID,PageName order by PageOrderID
```